# Apostrophe vs. Single Quote

Tags: punctuation, apostrophe

What is the **semantic** difference between **apostrophe** and **single quote**?

I see people use both of them interchangeably, but people never create two words to denote one concept. There should be a difference.

Comment: Related: [Any reference on the usage of a backtick and single quotation mark like `this' ?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/17695/any-reference-on-the-usage-of-a-backtick-and-single-quotation-mark-like-this)

Comment: drm's answer is correct. Nonetheless, I have to take issue with your statement that "people never create two words to denote one concept". In fact, people do this *all the time*. They're called "synonyms" and we have tons of them.

Comment: No @JSBangs, I don't think so. Synonyms are fundamentally interchangeable words, not **exact** words.

Comment: @JSBangs makes a good point. Think of all the terms we have for the act of coitus, for example. (I chose that one because there are so many examples.)

Comment: @Robusto: That's slightly disingenuous. Exact synonyms abound in slang, obviously, and yours is one of *the* most common slang referents. But there are few (if any?) *exact* synonyms in "standard" vocabulary.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: So you are calling my statement insincere, cynical, or faux-naive?

Comment: @Robusto: I guess the nearest of those is 'cynical', but no - I called it "slightly disingenuous". I doubt you disagree with my follow-on statements, so it's slightly deceptive to imply that slang words for "act of coitus" was much of a random choice. True synonyms are largely the exclusive province of slang.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Where did I imply randomness? I gave an explicit reason for my choice.

Comment: And many years later I am wondering why both "car" and "automobile" exist and what difference there is in meaning for them.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

An easy way to differentiate:

An [apostrophe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apostrophe) is only used *within* or at the very end of a word - it is part of the word.

> In English, it serves three purposes:
>
> - The marking of the omission of one or more letters (as in the [contraction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraction_%28grammar%29) of *do not* to *don't*).
> - The marking of [possessive case](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Possessive_case) (as in *the cat's whiskers*).
> - The marking as [plural](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plural) of written items that are not words established in English orthography (as in *P's and Q's, the late 1950's*). (This is considered incorrect by some; see [Use in forming certain plurals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apostrophe#Use_in_forming_certain_plurals). The use of the apostrophe to form plurals of proper words, as in *apple's*, *banana's*, etc., is universally considered incorrect.)

[Single quotes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_quotes#Quotations_and_speech) are only used *around* words - they come in pairs, and are not part of any word.

> Single or double quotation marks denote either speech or a quotation.

Comment: Some linguists go so far as to say that [the apostrophe is a letter.](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=2664)

Comment: +1 for thoroughness and balance over the third purpose. Technically I should be upvoting Wikipedia maybe, but it was you who found and linked it in here.

Comment: There seems to be a bit of dispute as to when the third rule should apply.  IMHO, it should be applied fairly broadly in cases where it may assist visual parsing and would not introduce ambiguity.  For example, when talking about automatic teller machines, the plural is not pronounced "ai-tee-em-ess", but "ai-tee-ems"; to my mind, writing "ATM's" makes clear that the "s" should be regarded differently from the preceding letters. Other typographical indicators (e.g. italics or hairspaces) may be better than an apostrophe, but in many contexts the latter is more likely to copy/paste correctly.

Comment: @supercat - I thought it worth noting that, to my mind, ATMs already makes it clear that the "s" should be regarded differently than the preceding letters because it is not in uppercase.

Comment: @bubbleking: True, in cases where all letters of an initialism are in uppercase.  In the case of something like PhDs, however, or in all-caps signage, that distinction may not be available.  Someone who has just been reading about transient voltage suppressors or credit default swaps might at first glance fail to correctly parse an all-caps sign advertising a sale on television sets and compact disks (I know that I at least have mis-parsed such signage at first glance).

Comment: @supercat - Agreed. Those are good examples.

Comment: This is _mostly_ correct. I take issue with saying that an apostrophe is _only_ used within or at the end of a word. There are plenty of examples of contractions with leading apostrophes:  'tis the season; '68 Chevy Malibu; class of '24. Additionally, when properly typeset, it should never use a single-open-quote mark instead of an apostrophe. An apostrophe is typically interchangeable with a single-close-quote, but it can be different within a more specialized font face. One could be forgiven for using a neutral single quote in a pinch (an abhorrent anachronism of mechanical typewriters).

Comment: Just a quick follow-up to my previous comment regarding the validity of leading apostrophes being valid: here is a more in-depth description with a simple mnemonic provided at the end for getting it right. [Smart Quotes and Dumb Apostrophes](https://signalinc.com/smart-quotes-and-dumb-apostrophes/)

Answer (score 3):

You asked about the **semantic** difference, but there is also a **technical** difference - ASCII and typewriter keyboards do not have a 'single quote' character, only QUOTATION MARK ([U+0022](https://util.unicode.org/UnicodeJsps/character.jsp?a=0022)) and APOSTROPHE ([U+0027](https://util.unicode.org/UnicodeJsps/character.jsp?a=0027)). So people typing on traditional mechanical and computer keyboards use apostrophes both within and around words.

Some editor applications have context-sensitive "smart quotes" that substitutes typesetting characters when an ASCII character is typed:

- LEFT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK [U+2018](https://util.unicode.org/UnicodeJsps/character.jsp?a=2018)
- RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK [U+2019](https://util.unicode.org/UnicodeJsps/character.jsp?a=2019)
- LEFT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK [U+201C](https://util.unicode.org/UnicodeJsps/character.jsp?a=201c)
- RIGHT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK [U+201D](https://util.unicode.org/UnicodeJsps/character.jsp?a=201d)

And to make things more confusing, such applications may also substitute a right single quotation mark for an apostrophe even within words.

Comment: What's even more confusing is that Unicode says that U+2019 RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK should be used for contractions such as "we’ve". https://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode13.0.0/ch06.pdf (page 270)

Answer (score 0):

### **TLDR:**

The apostrophe's proper useage denotes possessive form or missing letters/numbers.

The 'Single Quote' is to denote a quote within a quote.  Also, often used for emphasis.

## Apostrophes

Apostrophes are utilized to denote possessive form of a noun and/or the missing letters/numbers when:

- contracting multiple words
- shortening a single word or date

### *Position*

Apostrophes may occur before within and rarely at the end.

### Missing Letters Examples

1. Within Word:

   - There isn't, to my knowledge, a use of apostrophes to denote a plural noun.
   - Still, can't say for sure there isn`t though a plural word place it at the end & not between its letters.
2. End of the Word:

   - Others' background, training, and education may know more.
   - Most common use is to show nouns' plural and possessive form.
   - Also, ye' see ta' use of apostros' for slang 'nd da' speakers'wi't accent.
3. Beginning of the Word:

   - Since `67, seen primarily at beginning of dates.
   - 'et da' be th't slang usage ta' think of.

### *NOTE:*

Pronouns, acronyms and certain words denote possession without the apostrophes.

### 'It'

- It's = contraction of 'It is'
- Its  = possessive form of 'It'

### Single Quote

A 'Single Quote'is used for quotes within a quote.  The off label usage is for emphasis when italics, bold, and underlining isn't enough.

1. Quotes within a quote:

   Our English/Pshycology professor claimed, "The author states 'Word Processer's use of Smart Apostrophes are leading to the demise of the apostrophe by converting any at the start and end of a word to the angle quote.' which clearly shows ludite tendencies in the author's subconscious."
2. Emphasis

   - Using 'single apostrophes' to call out a teen or phrase may be more common than for quote with a quote.
   - SMS before 'smart phones' added emojis led to many special characters being used to emphasize the nuances lost with text.

### *Edited*

- The post saw most apostrophes, (except with `67), as a 'code command'.  This meant they where hidden and changed the font after the apostrophes.
- Except for **`67**' all apostrophes where switched for 'single quotes'.  I may have missed a couple.

Thanks for reaching the end.

- Have a great week.

Comment: This would benefit from sources or citations.  Welcome to EL&U.  Please do take a moment to [tour] the site and see the [help].

Comment: You seem to be under the impression that ` is an apostrophe. It is not. Unicode calls it a "grave accent", with ' being an apostrophe, and ’ being a "right single quotation mark". In practice, the "right single quotation mark" looks like a printer's apostrophe, so that's what is used. The grave accent is never used as an apostrophe. Ironically your edit has corrected the answer (with the exception of "`67").

Comment: 'There isn't, to my knowledge, a use of apostrophes to denote a plural noun.' This has already been debated elsewhere on ELU and the jury is out. '...  to my knowledge' usually indicates a lack of research shown (and, one might deduce, a lack of research).