# quotation mark to indicate possession after quotation marks indicating the title of a short story

Tags: grammar, quotations, quotation-marks, titles

Would it be wrong to write, for example:

"Slight Rebellion Off Madison" 's characters, plot, and themes develop in the same way as chapter 17 of *Catcher in the Rye*, only its point of view is different.

(Not wanting to say Salinger's characters for reasons of repetition from previous sentences.)

Or:

Some critics have written that "The Lottery"'s bleak mood evokes a tension comparable to that moment in John 8:7 when a group of scribes and Pharisees gathered to stone a woman found guilty of adultery.

And how would one handle the spacing between " and 's ?

[[these are just an examples, mind you]]

Comment: Not the answer you're looking for, but I would reword that as _The characters, plot, and themes **of "Slight Rebellion Off Madison"** develop..._.

Comment: Thanks, I was leaning in this direction---adding an "of"  and turning things around. And you pretty much convinced me.  It is more elegant to avoid the trio of hash marks, I suppose.

Comment: I've posted my comment as an answer in case you want to upvote it or mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: It should be noted that `'` (or `’`) pulls double duty, being used as both an apostrophe (for possession) and a single quotation mark (for quoting). When used to indicate possession, it is not a “quotation mark” at all, but an apostrophe. Since we use the same character (and keyboard key) for them, it doesn’t help answer your question, but just so you know. See [related Q&A on that](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/36046/24589).

Answer (score 3):

Given that the popular convention seems to be to put [short story](https://thewritepractice.com/do-you-italicize-book-titles/) [titles](https://www.writermag.com/2012/08/02/do-i-italicize-the-title/) in [quotes](https://data.grammarbook.com/blog/capitalization/titles-of-books-plays-articles-etc-underline-italicize-use-quotation-marks/), it might best to reword the sentence to avoid the issue altogether:

> The characters, plot, and themes ***of "Slight Rebellion Off Madison"*** develop in the same way as chapter 17 of Catcher in the Rye, only its point of view is different.